# Position sticky doesn't work on mozilla neither in safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

Position sticky doesn't work on mozilla neither in safari browser, but in chrome it's working perfectly. Is anyone there who can help me.. I know it we can make it don't by many others way which is "javaScript" but I don't wanna use javaScript in it.

```css
table thead th { position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky; top: -1px; background: #ccc;}
.table-div {max-height: 200px; overflow: auto;}
.table-div table td {min-width: 200px;}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row nopadding">
    <div class="table-div table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <th>head1</th>
            <th>head1</th>
            <th>head1</th>
            <th>head1</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 50px;"></td>
                <td style="height: 50px;"></td>
                <td style="height: 50px;"></td>
                <td style="height: 50px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 50px;"></td>
                <td style="height: 50px;"></td>
                <td style="height: 50px;"></td>
                <td style="height: 50px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 50px;"></td>
                <td style="height: 50px;"></td>
                <td style="height: 50px;"></td>
                <td style="height: 50px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 50px;"></td>
                <td style="height: 50px;"></td>
                <td style="height: 50px;"></td>
                <td style="height: 50px;"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Position: sticky` is not a standard, so it may works, depending of the browser and the version, or even you need to set some flags in web browser config.

You can check this availavility here:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

As you can see, in known issues:

`Chrome, Firefox and Safari 7 & below do not appear to support sticky table headers. (see also Firefox bug)`

Comment: so is there any other way to make table header sticky on scroll without using java script??

Comment: @Samar well, you have two options: 1) instead using a table use a div structure (making more complex html, css and making harder code readibility) 2) use javascript. If there is other ones, I don't know right now. There is any reason to not use JS?

Answer (score 0):

Since its only `table` elements which aren't responding properly to `position: sticky` and since it's only the `th` elements you want to apply to the sticky positioning to, why not build a custom `thead` and apply `position: sticky` to that custom `thead`?

**Working Example:**

```css
.custom-thead {
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
top: -1px;
min-width: 816px;
}

.custom-thead .custom-th {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
left: 2px;
min-width: 202px;
margin-right: 2px;
background-color: #ccc;
}

.table-div {
max-height: 200px;
overflow: auto;
}

.table-div table td {
min-width: 200px;
height: 50px;
background-color: #eee;
}

.custom-th {
font-weight: bold;
}

.custom-th, td {
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row nopadding">
<div class="table-div table-responsive">

<div class="custom-thead">
<div class="custom-th">head1</div><div class="custom-th">head1</div><div class="custom-th">head1</div><div class="custom-th">head1</div>
</div>

<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>9</td>
<td>10</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>12</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>13</td>
<td>14</td>
<td>15</td>
<td>16</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```