# Position sticky horizontal scrolling with display grid acting weird in Firefox and Safari

Tags: html, css, firefox, grid, sticky

I'm trying to create a reusable Table component in React, which has sticky columns (upon horizontal scrolling) with `display: grid` and `position: sticky`.

I started the implementation in Chrome, where everything works as expected, so I checked Firefox and Safari how the component works there. Unfortunately, Firefox and Safari don't handle `position: sticky` the same way as Chrome does.

---

#### Example:

For the sake of brevity, here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kristof0425/pen/bGNrmZW?editors=0100), where the problem can be checked.

---

#### What I've found:

For testing, I made the first and the last two columns in the table sticky. What I've found is that Firefox renders the last two columns' `th` and `td` elements as `position: absolute`. 

Whenever I resize the table to a smaller width the table's `scrollWidth` *(should be the sum of all the column's `width`)* and `clientWidth` *(should be the `table` element's `width`)* **are the same on Firefox** and **are different values on Chrome**.

Eg.:

```js
// Firefox & Safari
table.scrollWidh = 657
table.clientWidth = 657

// Chrome
table.scrollWidth = 800
table.clientWidth = 657
```

---

TBH, I'm not sure whether I've found a bug in Firefox and Safari at the same time or which browser I should trust now. Or maybe there is a CSS property missing from my implementation.

Have you run into this? Do you have a hint if I'm missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Position sticky doesn't work on mozilla neither in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45414597/position-sticky-doesnt-work-on-mozilla-neither-in-safari)

Comment: @Awais Unfortunately no. In that question, the OP was interested in making the table head element sticky. Making `thead` sticky (vertically) is not supported in Chrome according to caniuse and also this is not what I'm looking for. I'd like to make `th` and `td` elements sticky (horizontally).

Comment: Ok take an idea form this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811653/table-with-fixed-header-and-fixed-column-on-pure-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, I was able to fix the problem. The solution required some JS modifications.

The problem was that on Firefox and Safari the `scrollWidth` of the `table` element did not contain the width of the columns, which had `position: sticky` CSS rule.
In order to fix that, I introduced a `::before` pseudo element to the `table`.
The style definition looks like this now:

```css
table {
  ...
  position: relative;
}

table::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

I calculate the sum of all the columns' widths and apply that to the pseudo element.

After that, the `scrollWidth` is going to have the correct value on Firefox and Safari as well.

Unfortunately, there is no pure CSS solution for this problem. Luckily I had to measure the column widths anyway as I need them for the correct `left` and `right` values.